# Error rotating contextmenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, runtime-error

I've been getting this error throughout my program when I open a context menu then rotate the screen.

`03-19 16:09:25.627: E/InputQueue-JNI(11610): channel '41c6ffc0 AtchDlg:xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.TyContextMenuActivity (client)' ~ 
Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8`

I stripped the code down to the most basic form I can come up with and am still getting the error so I think it is in the android code.

```
public class TyContextMenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this)
        {

            @Override
            protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu)
            {
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu);
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Rotate Screen");
                menu.addSubMenu("90 degrees");
            }

        };
        textView.setText("hold me");
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(50);
        registerForContextMenu(textView);
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to eliminate this error?

Comment: This error is about something with JNI, which is the native programming in C. If you're not doing this, this error is probably just from the system and you can ignore it. Does your app crash when rotating? If yes, post your whole logcat instead.

Comment: It doesn't crash but it generates the posted error message which generates an email.  We need to keep it from showing up.  What I posted is all that appears in logcat.  It appears to be a bug in the native code to me but I'm hoping for a work around if that's the case.